# Linked dropdown checkbox filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dropdown

I'm quite new to web-development, and have a problem which I can't solve. I have a table which has 3 items: car, color and motor type. Table example is here:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
        <th>Car</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Motor type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mercedes</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Petrol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mercedes</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Diesel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>VW</td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Hybrid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>VW</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Diesel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfa Romeo</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Diesel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfa Romeo</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Petrol</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add 3 dropdowns with checkboxes to filter selected items, one for car, one for color and one for motor type. Items in dropdown should be filled dynamically, based on the items in the table.
For example:

- First dropdown will be consisted of 3 checkboxes: Mercedes, VW and Alfa Romeo
- Second will have Blue, Red, Yellow and Green
- and third one will have Petrol, Diesel and Hybrid

Also, when I select Mercedes, for example, Yellow and Green color should be hidden in second dropdown, and Hybrid should be hidden in third dropdown, since there aren't any Yellow/Green/Hybrid Mercedes.

Can someone please help with writing the appropriate JavaScript/jQuery file?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: are you using database?

Comment: Yes, but I think that it doesn't make any difference. I have already handled filling the table with database values.

Comment: what language you can use for fetch values from database

Comment: Swift with Vapor framework. Swift fetches something I need from database, then creates a "Node", for example a list of cars, and passes it to HTML file, which I can loop and/or display directly in HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

First, set onchange to the checkboxs to track with is selected.

Then, in the onchange event,  use the index of the items you want to hide items of dropdownlist:

`document.getElementById('your dropdownlist id').options[index].style.display = 'none';`

this is a example.

```js
function changeItemsOfDropDown() {
  var drop = document.getElementById("optionDrop");

  for (var i = 0; i < drop.options.length; i++) {
    if (drop.options[i].value == "Green" || drop.options[i].value == "Blue") {
      drop.options[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function fillItemsToDropDown() {
  var drop = document.getElementById("optionDrop");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = option.value = "test" + i;
    drop.add(option);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="changeItemsOfDropDown()" >Click to hide items of Green and Blue</input>
<button type="checkbox" onchange="fillItemsToDropDown()" >Fill new options to dropdownlist</button>
<br>
<select id="optionDrop">
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Green">Green</option>
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: It's part of it, but I still don't know how to fill dropdown checkboxes, and filter table content after some of them are selected.

Answer (score 0):

i am write in php, you can modify this

this is only idea for you

```
//fetch from database
<input type="checkbox" value="Mercedes" onclick="car_fun(this.value)"> Mercedes
<input type="checkbox" value="VW" onclick="car_fun(this.value)"> VW
<input type="checkbox" value="Alfa Romeo" onclick="car_fun(this.value)"> Alfa Romeo

<select id="color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<select id="type">
<option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
<option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
<option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
</select>

<script>
function car_fun(car)
{
$.ajax({
url:// your url,
data:"$car_name="+car,
type:"post",
dataType:"json",
success:function(result)
{
$("#color").html(result.color);
$("#type").html(result.type);
}
});
}
</script>
```

fetch the value from database using the passed car value